# RedirectAction adds an additional context name in URL while redirecting to another action in Struts.xml

Tags: jsp, redirect, struts2

I am trying to redirect request to another action in struts2 using result type redirectAction.

```
<action name="UpdateTrouserMeasurementAction" method="UpdateTrouserMeasurement"
        class="com.example.UserDetails.UpdateTrouserMeasurementAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">UserAccountDisplayAction</result>
        <result name="error">LoginCheck.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

It is redirecting to the **UserAccountDisplayAction** but adding an extra context name in the URL as below:

```
http://www.example.com/Example/UserAccountDisplayAction
```

but it should be: `http://www.example.com/UserAccountDisplayAction

So I am getting the below error:

**HTTP Status 404 - /Example/Example/MyAccount.jsp**

Below is the Action to which I am redirecting:

```
    <action name="UserAccountDisplayAction" method="execute"
        class="com.example.UserDetails.UserAccountDisplayAction">
        <result name="success">MyAccount.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">LoginCheck.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

I am using redirectAction to create post+redirect+get scenario as **UpdateTrouserMeasurementAction** handles a post request.

Above Actions are in same package element which looks like this : 
 `<package name="securePackage" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What do the `<package>` elements for the two actions look like?

Comment: Actions are in same package.<package> element looks like this : **<package name="securePackage" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">**

Comment: @StefanBartel I have updated the question.

Comment: I hoped, the package namespace would explain it. So, next question: What is the actual url for the post request to `UpdateTrouserMeasurementAction` (both in jsp code and in the generated html code)?

Comment: Where do you run this code?

Comment: @RomanC Ubuntu machine, server apache2-tomcat7

Comment: @Arpit If you want to resolve this you should post server apache2 config

Comment: @RomanC Roman in previous comments you asked me to provide sever config to resolve this. Can you please tell me what configuration you will require for this.

Comment: Forget it, just use it in local Tomcat. If it has the same error then update it with the latest version and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, on local its working completely fine @RomanC

Comment: Then it's problem with Apache, it's off topic here, try to ask it on serverfault, and of course it's not struts2 problem, isn't it?

Comment: @RomanC Thanks for your suggestion, yes it was Apache configuration issue that I managed o resolve after you suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the format of your redirect is incorrect.  Maybe it should be like below, but the exact syntax can depend on your struts version.  Also, after years of using struts I really think forwarding from action to action is bad practice.  If you want to use java code from another action you should instead subroutine it.

```
<action name="UpdateTrouserMeasurementAction" method="UpdateTrouserMeasurement"
    class="com.example.UserDetails.UpdateTrouserMeasurementAction">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
       <param name="actionName">UserAccountDisplayAction</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error">LoginCheck.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Yes, we can use params in result and actually I will implement that but as of now its not making any difference. What do you mean by **If you want to use java code from another action you should instead subroutine it.** I am using redirectAction because in further requirements I will have to pass some more parameters in **UpdateTrouserMeasurementAction** Action.

Comment: Forwarding from action to action makes the code really hard to follow and debug.  I have seen nightmares where developers were forwarding through 5 actions.  People do this because the want to execute the code in the next action down the chain.  Instead break that code out in to java utility subroutines and call from the action you are in.  You might need to add more forwards from that action but it will result in much better code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I really appreciate it. I will look forward to implement this way too, but I will be grateful to know why redirectAction is adding an extra context name in URL?

Comment: What? Is it relevant?

Comment: Well, technically a redirect goes back to the browser and the browser asks for the page you told it to redirect to.  I have never used this "redirect" in struts.  You might be thinking that it just goes straight to the other action but maybe it does go back to the browser and that is why it would borrow the URL from the previous call.  If you just want to forward to another action you just put its name in place of where you would put the jsp name with your extension on it like UserAccountDisplayAction.do.  Keep in mind you are refering to the action mapping in this case, not the java class.

Comment: Putting Action name in place of JSP name in result doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm.. Part of the problem is I'm more of a struts 1.x guy.  I know this is how I would do a mapping there.  <action  path="/ViewGuestFolioFromInHouseList"
        type="com.choicehotels.pmweb.actions.FindReservationWithAccountNumberAction"
        name="FindReservationForm"
        scope="session"
        roles="frontdesk"
        validate="true"
        input="/view_in_house_list.jsp">
        <forward name="failure" path="/view_in_house_list.jsp" />
        <forward name="successful" path="/GuestFolioFromInhouseList.do" />
    </action>

Comment: Maybe the forward slash is needed?

Comment: @javaMoca I know you mean well, but making wild guesses about a framework you don't really know, isn't going to help anybody. You are right though: Using `redirectAction` to chain java code together is bad practice. That's what the `chain` result is for. And using `chain` is rightfully shunned for all the reasons you gave above. But there are good reasons to use `redirectAction`. The redirect-after-post pattern is considered best practice for most web frameworks. And it's fair to assume that it applies, when you redirect from an **Update** action to a **Display** action.

Comment: @StefanBartel OP said *forwarding from action to action*, does it make sense? Redirects or forwards to action never been a bad practice. Result type "chain" you should use with caution just because it's heavy and difficult to implement but it's never been a bad practice though.

Comment: Its been lot of days now but I am still stuck with the same problem.
@StefanBartel  you are right, I want to redirect to implement post-redirect-get pattern.

Comment: @RomanC Roman in previous comments you asked me to provide sever config to resolve this. Can you please tell me what configuration you will require for this.